# VirtualBoxのゲストOSでUbuntu 64bitが選択できない

Tags: virtualbox

**やろうとしていること**
VirtualBoxでUbnutuの64bitを動かす。

**発生している問題**
VTxとVTdを有効、hyper-vを無効にしているのに64bitの選択肢が出てきません。
32bitのままで、起動したらエラーが出ます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 念のため確認ですが、ホストOS(VirtualBoxを実行しているOS=Windows10?)は64bitでしょうか？

Comment: vtxとか有効にしてたら出てくると思うんだけど...BIOSで設定変更して保存してないなんてオチないですか？保存しないで終了する選んでたり...　ちなみに、出てくるエラー画面の画像上げたりできませんか？

Comment: 64bitのwindows10を使用しています。

Answer (score 0):

ホストOS側のBIOS設定で「仮想化機能」をあらかじめ有効にしておく必要があるそうです。
お使いのPC/マザーボードのメーカーによって詳細は異なると思うので、ご自身の環境で確認してみてください。

参考：
[【仮想OS】virtualboxで64bitOSが選択できない場合](http://acball.hatenablog.com/entry/2013/11/05/205712)
[VirtualBox：仮想マシンの作成で64bit OSを選択可能にする方法](http://did2memo.net/2015/07/10/virtualbox-64-bit-os/)

Comment: biosに入ってvtxを有効にしましたが設定が適用されないように感じます(ちゃんと保存していますが)。VirtualCheckerを使ってちゃんと仮想化できているか確認したら未対応と出ています

Answer (score 0):

WindowsでHyper-Vが有効になっているとvtxが使用できないようです。
[コントロールパネル]-[プログラム]の「Windows の機能の有効化または無効化」で、Hyper-Vにチェックがされていたりしませんか。